# Android studio freeze for long time on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to android development app so I installed android studio on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop version. ANDROID STUDIO deep Freeze automatically for sometime that decreases my enthusiasm to create an app..! Please give me solution to solve this problem.! My laptop configuration are -RAM 8gib,AMD processor,gallium0.4 graphics and OS type is 64 bit,hard disk 313.0GB

Comment: What's displayed when you start the application in `gnome-terminal`? "Application freezes" is too vague to help you.

Comment: The application open with no lagging.I type code and run.After sometime its freeze with no response only we can minimize it. Please give me some solution.As I was mentioned my RAM was 2gb not 8gb.